# How to move store swicther after header links in magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to move store switcher after header links and also move search bar after links. how to do that??
I'm using blank as parent

Answer (score 2):

### How to move an element

To move an element you need to use the `<move element="block-name-to-be-moved" destination="block/container-you-want-to-move-it-to" />` - Official docs can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv)

### In your case

So to move the store switcher after the header links you would use:

```
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.links" />
```

And to move the search bad after the nav (I presume that's what you mean by links) you would use:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav" />
```

### How to find block/container names

You can usually find out the destination by searching the module, for example if you search `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` you will see that the name of the search block is `top.search`.

Now if you search all the Magento modules XML files for `top.search` you will find `vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`. In here you can see that `top.search` is inside `header-wrapper`.